# Xcode is damaged and refuse to run the code

Tags: xcode, debugging, swiftui, error-handling

When I press "Build" and/or "Run" buttons in Xcode (SwiftUI), it shows me an error and I get this message:

One of the paths in DEVELOPMENT_ASSET_PATHS does not exist: /Users/mohammedshaheen/Downloads/Clicker/Clicker/Preview Content

Comment: Try cleaning your build folder, then restarting xcode.

Comment: Is your project folder in your Downlisd folder ? If no, then you may have added data from this folder but without copying these and then deleted the original data from Download folder. BTW , try to not use download folder for important data, but only for its purpose : downloading data and then remove these from this folder if you need theses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked with me! If the file "Preview Content" is not existing in your main project file, just create a new file called "Preview Content".

And the name is based on what is shown to you.